# can't execute transactions in hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

this is my transaction definition in the script file is :

```
async function tradeCommodity(transfer) {...}
```

but the composer playground throws an error for not detecting the transaction and it's input.
how's the proper way of coding the transactions?

Comment: Please show the exact error you are seeing, the Model File, and the script logic

Answer (score 0):

i belive i know where the problem is. as far as i can see , you havn't passed any parameters to your `async function` as the function parameter.
the lines before the functions definitions are not just comments that you skip, you will pass your parameter here. so be careful.
the syntax for sending your parameter is like this:

```
/**
 * @param {org.example.empty."transaction name" } "instance name" 
*/
    async function tradeCommodity(transfer) {...}
```

i hope it works.

Comment: is that necessary to instantiate for our transaction,i mean , doesn't the composer know what to pass to the transactions?

Comment: you can name your function and the passed parameter to it anything you like but you should pay attention to the parameter that you pass to it.

Comment: @Parsa - Transaction Processor structure, is described in the Composer docs -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/js_scripts